# Is the link between shadows a refraction of the light?

Tags: visible-light, refraction

When two objects in the sunlight approach, if you look at their shadows, they form a link when they are really close, is that an example of refraction? If so, is it the same as the refraction we see on the water (light traveling in a diferent medium)? The different medium being the edje of the objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Very strange shadow phenomenon](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94235/)

Comment: Yeah, thats it, thank you. Should I delete the question?